Extract(year from column) yields year with one decimal in SQL, why?
I used this to extract year from datetime:
select extract(year from orders.OrderDate)

It gave me year with one decimal. e.g. 2019.0
Why is this? Any feedback would be appreciated!
I also tried:
YEAR(column)
DATEPART(year, column)

None of these worked.

EXTRACT is not common to all DBMS. Please add a tag for your exact DBMS (SQL-Server, MySQL, PostGres, Oracle).

Because function "extract" Returns number, and probably you should set proper number formatting in your IDE, or cast output of the function as string

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
